# woocommerce: don't have adding a downloadable product options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in adding a downloadable product in wordpress store,in  product data, cant see virtual and downloadable options to check.
drop-down list and check-boxes are disappeared.
second problem is : dont have variation tab

woocommerce plugin version is 2.6.8

Comment: Kindly share the "system status" output of woocommerce